# How to define "base href " dynamically in Angular 8 application from index.html?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, base-url, angular-cli-v8

How to define "base href " dynamically in Angular 8 application from index.html?

Earlier I used `--base-href`, but now it is not supported.

Comment: As far as I can tell from the documentation, —base-href still works.. is it not setting it in index.html in your dist folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set base href dynamically by setting the property through script and getting it in NgModule.

```
  //index.html
    <script>
      window['base-url'] = window.location.pathname;
    </script>
```

And in your module you need to use

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: window['base-url']}]
})
```